# What is the format of valid entrypoint names?

Tags: michelson, protocol

Are there any constraints on valid entrypoint names?

Answer (score 1):

The entrypoint name must be a [valid annotation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/michelson.html#syntax):

> An annotation is a sequence of characters that matches the regular
> expression
> `@%|@%%|%@|[@:%][<sub>0</sub>-9a-zA-Z][<sub>0</sub>-9a-zA-Z\\.%@]\*`.
> Note however that `@%`, `@%%` and `%@` are special annotations and are
> not allowed everywhere.

Furthermore, entrypoint names are also [limited to 31 characters](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_008_PtEdo2Zk/lib_protocol/script_ir_translator.ml#L2778).

(Note: there is a currently a [bug](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/851) that permits invalid entrypoint
annotations to be given to literal address. Such addresses should not
be expected to function normally.)

While in no way reserved, the entrypoint name `%root` is often used by
convention to name the root when using a `%default` entrypoint).